# AJAX - Get cross-origin XML data with username and password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to do a cross-origin request to a server to retrieve some XML data via AJAX. The XML data is password protected and I have to enter credentials in order to access it. I'm trying to autopopulate these fields so that obviously me nor the user has to write them in every time they want to retrieve some data but can't seem to succcessfully pass these through with my request as it still prompts me for a username and password. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "https://example.com/api",  
    data:"?&mydata=1&moredata=2",
    dataType: "jsonp xml",   
    crossDomain:true,        
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.withCredentials = true; 
    },
    username:"user",
    password:"pass",   
    success: function(xml){

        console.log(xml)

    }
});
```

I'm pretty suer i've added all the necessary configuration. Can anyone spot if i've missed something or if there's an alternative way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Does the AJAX request itself work? Do you get any errors in the console? If this is a cross domain request you're more than likely being blocked by the SOP.

Comment: Yea I get my data back no problem when I manually type in the username and password

Comment: That wasn't what I asked - have you checked the response from the above AJAX request in the console to see if it's working, or if not, to see what the error status code and description is

Comment: you might have to guide me a bit where to look here as it returns a fairly large object. Within the object I see the the statuscode object but with loads of different trees so not too sure where to look from here?

Comment: i am however geting the following console error: Unexpected token <

Comment: That error means that you've told jQuery to expect JSON back from the request but you're actually getting XML or HTML, most likely due to an error message being rendered by the receiving server.

Comment: If I click the link I can see the XML that is returned. Problem is if I change dataType to "xml" then I can't do a cross origin request so not sure hwat to do here?

Comment: In that case you cannot make the request using JS code. I assumed the response was coming back as JSONP (which would be valid for cross-domain) and you simply wanted to work with it as XML. If the receiving server does not include CORS headers in the response then they are expressly disallowing any third party to make a request to them via JS code. You'll need to make the request using server side code instead, eg PHP or C#

Comment: OK makes sense, will look at some php examples and post an answer here if I find any successful ones